# Parsing .o files with WindowsApi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am on a quest to find a function's size, in bytes. An old method I tried, which calculates the size at runtime:

```
DWORD function(){
// Do something
}
DWORD functionEnd(){
// Do nothing - meant to simply delimit the end of function()
}

DWORD size = function - functionEnd
```

Doesn't work. With this method I get random sizes, which are static, and therefore never change regardless of the contents of the function.

Therefore, I thought of possibly compiling my function in another file into a .o object file and then parsing it, extracting the function in bytes from the .text section and calculating its size that way.

However, searching on the web I have found nothing in the way of parsing a .o file with WindowsApi, albeit I found plenty information concerning doing this on Linux (https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-execute-an-object-file-part-1/)

So are there native Windows functions to do this?

Comment: The size of a function is not meaningful. Code describes program behaviour, not the operations executed by the computer. How the compiler produces the operations that implement the described behaviour is up to the compiler. The function might even be optimized out and not exist.

Comment: In other words, the only way to do this is the hard coded way - look at the assembly, find the function and its first ret, and calculate first byte to last?

Comment: As for the file format, google `elf specification`. While I largely agree with user4581301's comments, I've used what you do above as a crude method in the past with some success - that can vary with the dev environment, of course, and you'll definitely want both symbols to be referenced - referencing `size` here may be enough to ensure that. Note also that functions typically start at 4, 8, or 16-byte aligned addresses, depending on the platform, so adding a few small instructions to a function might not change its size when calculated this way.

Comment: What compiler? MSVC generates .obj (COFF), not .o (ELF). For reading COFF, a quick search yields https://github.com/serge1/COFFI for example (not pure WinAPI)..

Comment: ***So are there native Windows functions to do this?*** I would doubt that the OS would have such functionality since Microsoft's compiler msvc does not use .o files instead it uses .obj files.

Comment: I should have taken another pass at that comment. What I mean to say is you can't find an easy and consistent way to get the size of a function is because there is no such way. Your brute force approach parsing the output object file may be the only way to do it. But don't expect it to be consistent across compilers, compiler options or other changes.

Comment: I am currently using MSVC for my first method (the one which doesn't work). I need to grab this function size specifically when it is compiled for execution on Windows, and parsing the .o seems to use mostly Linux specific functions, so no point in using gcc. Therefore I probably need to create and parse a .obj file. Pardon me, I thought a .o file was standard for both Linux and Windows compilers.

Comment: I don't require much consistency. However, being a bit new to assembly I have had a bit of a hard time finding my own functions in IDA or OllyDBG. On IDA, my function written with inline assembly (x86) would display the error "sp-analysis failed", which, according to what I found on the web, happens because IDA is better at interpreting compiler written assembly, rather than "modified" assembly. Are there any methods to help in this bruteforcing task? And after I've found my function, may I call it, utilize it as usual in any other file (.exe)?

Comment: @functionhunter there are quite a few ways you can find your function with IDA - the easiest is to import the corresponding .pdb file for your executable, which will provide function names & type information for everything in the exe. Another option would be to mark your function as `__declspec( dllexport )`, that way msvc will create an entry for function in your export directory that you can directly follow to your function in IDA.

Comment: If you get "sp-analysis failed" that most likely means that your inline assembly doesn't follow the conventions - i.e. if you push something onto the stack you need to pop it before the function returns, make sure you first decrement esp before using that space, etc... additionally if your function is `__declspec(naked)` you're also on the hook for writing a correct prologue + epilogue. As long as your asm is well behaved IDA should have no problem disassembling it.

Comment: Thank you very much, will look into that. The COFF library also looks very promising.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the observed behavior is different between C and C++. This question is tagged with both languages. Which language are you actually using? More importantly: What *problem* are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is finding the size of a function, in bytes, at runtime. Can be in bytes at any time, however trying to parse a file to find a function and decipher the compiler's asm is not much fun.

Comment: This is re-stating your proposed solution. The question is: What are you going to do with that information? Why is this value meaningful?

Comment: I have written a joe() function, which I must call to interact with the mama() function, in order to produce a recurring joe() mama() at runtime.

Comment: Where in that is it required to know the **size** of the functions? If you need to call `joe`, then use the syntax `joe()`. If you need `joe` to know about `mama`, then pass it the address of `mama`, i.e. `&mama`.

Comment: Right! Will take that into consideration. I believe I was incorrectly using the isoverweight() function at the end, which was messing up recursion.